# Could not get previous events when using DateRangesOverlap

Tags: calendar, sharepoint-calendar

I used DateRangesOverlap for fetching calendar events with recurring set to TRUE.

Below is the code :

```
SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
DateTime startDate = new DateTime(2009, 2, 1);
query.ExpandRecurrence = true;
query.CalendarDate = startDate;
query.Query = "<Where><DateRangesOverlap><FieldRef Name=\"EventDate\" /><FieldRef Name=\"EndDate\" /><FieldRef Name=\"RecurrenceID\" /><Value Type=\"DateTime\"><Now /></Value></DateRangesOverlap></Where>";
SPListItemCollection myItems = myList.GetItems(query);
```

My past events are not there.

I have mentioned the start date as below:

```
CalDate = new DateTime(2009,2,1)
```

But didnt worked out.. My calendar starts from today's date.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <Where>
      <DateRangesOverlap>
          <FieldRef Name='EventDate' />
          <FieldRef Name='EndDate' />
          <FieldRef Name='RecurrenceID' />
          <Value Type='DateTime'>
              <Today/>
          </Value>
      </DateRangesOverlap>
 </Where>
```

Instead of `<Now />` use `<Today/>`

Ref : [CAML Queries, DateRangesOverlap, and Today, oh my!](http://ditzydev.blogspot.com/2010/02/caml-queries-daterangesoverlap-and.html), see the comment on blog too!